# Can canvas context.fillText be made crisp (because context.translate 0.5/0.5 doesn't)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've tried to search through StackOverflow for a similar question, but I seem to only be able to find questions that are either "how do I draw text in <canvas>" (answer: fillText) or "how do I make crisp lines" (answer, 0.5 coordinate offsets, because canvas isn't an integer pixel grid), neither of which answer my question. Which is the following:

How do I get fillText to render text as crisp as the browser renders text as part of a normal page?

As a demonstration, take the page on http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/fontreftest/crisptest, which uses the following html+js (using html5 doctype):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>fillText</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      canvas { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; display: block; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <table><tr><td style="font: normal normal 400 12px/14px Arial">
      <div>This is some text in Arial.</div><div>This is some text in Arial.</div>
      <div>This is some text in Arial.</div><div>This is some text in Arial.</div>
      <div>This is some text in Arial.</div><div>This is some text in Arial.</div>
      <div>This is some text in Arial.</div><div>This is some text in Arial.</div>
      <div>This is some text in Arial.</div><div>This is some text in Arial.</div>
    </td><td>
      <canvas id="filltext0"></canvas><canvas id="filltext1"></canvas>
      <canvas id="filltext2"></canvas><canvas id="filltext3"></canvas>
      <canvas id="filltext4"></canvas><canvas id="filltext5"></canvas>
      <canvas id="filltext6"></canvas><canvas id="filltext7"></canvas>
      <canvas id="filltext8"></canvas><canvas id="filltext9"></canvas>
    </td><tr></table>
    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
      function drawTextIn(which)
      {
        var tstring = "This is some text in Arial",
            canvas = document.getElementById('filltext' + which),
            context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var fontCSS = "normal normal 400 12px/14px Arial";
        context.font = fontCSS;
        canvas.width = context.measureText(tstring).width;
        canvas.height = 14;
        // setting the width resets the context, so force the font again
        context.font = fontCSS;
        context.fillText(tstring,0 + i/10,12);
      }
      for(var i=0; i<10; i++) { drawTextIn(i); }
    --></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will generate a side-by-side view of ten lines rendered by the browser in Arial at 12px with a lineheight (size+leading) of 14px, in normal style and weight, and ten lines rendered with the same font properties using <canvas> elements, with every line calling fillText with a 0.1 shifted x-coordinate. The first line has x coordinate 0, the second 0.1, the third 0.2, etc.

No current browser that supports <canvas> that I have tried (Chrome 12, Firefox 5, Opera 11.50, Internet Explorer 9, Safari 5) renders the text the same as real text, regardless of x-coordinate shift.

So the main thing I'm now wondering is whether or not there exists a (normal, fast) way to make a browser draw text to a <canvas> with the same crispness as it draws text to the page when it's just placing text.

I've read http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/canvas.html#text, http://blog.thesoftwarefactory.be/2009/04/drawing-crisp-lines-on-html5-canvas.html, http://joubert.posterous.com/crisp-html-5-canvas-text-on-mobile-phones-and, and http://www.bel.fi/~alankila/lcd/ - none of these cover the subject. The last offers an interesting approach, but one that can only be used if the canvas is empty, which is too limited to be of real-world use, neat as it is (it's too expensive to construct a new canvas for every line of text, call fillTExt and then clean it up using scanlines, and then copy the text over with alpha blending).

So.... can this be done? If you know how, I'd really, really like to know how to achieve this. And if you think the answer is no: please, include links to official specs that demonstrate why that answer is the right answer... I need the peace of mind of an official spec saying I can't do what I want, or I'll just keep wondering whether some even smarter person might have answered this question with "yes" =P

Answer (score 3):

> So the main thing I'm now wondering is whether or not there exists a (normal, fast) way to make a browser draw text to a  with the same crispness as it draws text to the page when it's just placing text.

The short answer is sadly no. Different browsers are currently implementing subpixel rendering/anti-aliasing for text in wildly different ways, which leads to (for some browsers) their rendered HTML page text looking good but their Canvas text looking awful.

One possibility is to pre-render all of your text (Even if that means writing it on an HTML page and taking a screenshot) and using `drawImage`. This also has the benefit of being much faster than calls to `drawText`, but of course is not very dynamic at all.

Answer (score 0):

While the question is old, I came across the exact same issue. While digging in FireFox, I found a flag for canvas which did the trick: mozOpaque. When set, the font uses the correct LCD rendering and the text is crisp as other elements on the page. To test it, just put:

```
canvas.mozOpaque = true;
```

after your canvas creation. There is a catch: the canvas can't be transparent anymore, but it wasn't an issue for my use. May be Chrome/Safari/IE got something similar. I hope this helps !

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this in other browsers?