# Draw sharper text on a clear canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

The problem is that the `ctx.fillText()` produces text that are much blurrier than the text displayed in a normal webpage. In [this example](http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/fontreftest/crisptest/), the text on right is produced on canvas and on left is on using html only. It is taken from this question [Can canvas context.fillText be made crisp (because context.translate 0.5/0.5 doesn't)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838461/can-canvas-context-filltext-be-made-crisp-because-context-translate-0-5-0-5-doe) but there was no answer to that question and the post may now be outdated.

I only need to output text to a clear canvas and I wish to increase the quality of the text. I am willing to do things pixel by pixel if that can make the text sharper. The problem is I don't know where to start.

Comment: One thing I've tried was to increase the dpi (sorta) by making the canvas width/height = 4x the normal size and style it down to the correct size. Like `<canvas width="400" height="400" style="width: 100px; height:100px"></canvas>";` I did this via a DPI variable that is multiplied on most of my width/heights while drawing, so I can still think in 1:1 ratios, but let the `var dpi=4;` do all the scaling on the entire canvas for me. Not sure if it'll help you though.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the browser: text on the left is rendered using standard ClearType rendering (at least on Windows ). On the right font anti-aliasing is gray scale. ClearType works when background in not transparent.

So try to fill the canvas by some non transparent color. If this will not work then this is a specific of font rendering of particular engine.

As an illustration on Windows:

This is font rendering in Sciter on solid background:
[image]
And this is the same document but with background:transparent (Aero Windows 7)
[image]

Solid background uses ClearType (use "open image in new tab in browser")